# Unusual results when comparing processors performance in libtomcrypt

Tags: c, performance, x86, benchmarking, cpu-architecture

I`m doing some research regarding processors performances in the libtomcrypt block ciphers functions. I am measuring the time that a CPU takes to complete a block cipher function with different file sizes.

The weird thing is that, when comparing a i5-4690 with a Celeron-G1840, the second one outperforms the first, which is counter-intuitive. Here is some plots that generated using the results. Is there anything that I'm missing? Shouldn't the i5 processor outperforms the Celeron for any file size?

[image: Plot for RC5 algorithm]

[image: Plot for DES algorithm]

[image: Plot for Blowfish algorithm]

[image: Plot for AES algorithm]

Comment: I don't know anything about libtomcrypt. If your benchmarks are single-threaded and memory-intensive, the Celeron processor might have a slightly smaller memory latency than the i5. If the benchmarks are multithreaded, then heavy inter-thread communication can make a 4-core system with 4 threads run slower than a 2-core one with just 2 threads. If you are using  DDR3-1333 DIMMs on i5, then the peak memory bandwidth on both is the same (you don't get memory bandwidth advantage on i5).

Comment: The i5 supports AVX2 while the Celeron does not. Does libtomcrypt automatically use AVX2? If it does this will scale down the CPU frequency and potentially reduce performance if the gain from using AXV2 is not big enough to compensate for the lower frequence. See eg. https://blog.cloudflare.com/on-the-dangers-of-intels-frequency-scaling/